# how to use glob with sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, glob, sql-like

I have a database of 23,000 words. I want to have the query return all words that start with a certain search string. After reading [sqlite LIKE problem in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179563/sqlite-like-problem-in-android) I was able to get a working query using LIKE. Here it is:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

String [] sqlSelect = { KEY_WORD };
String sqlTables = TABLE_WORDS;
//String selection = KEY_FUZZYWORD + " =?"; // for an exact match
String selection = KEY_FUZZYWORD + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { searchString + "%" };
String limit = Integer.toString(WORD_QUERY_LIMIT);

qb.setTables(sqlTables);
Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, limit);
```

The key lines are

```
String selection = KEY_FUZZYWORD + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { searchString + "%" };
```

But I also read [Why do we need the GLOB clause in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280980/why-do-we-need-the-glob-clause-in-sqlite) Case sensitivity is fine for my situation so I thought I would try it. How do you set this up using SQLiteQueryBuilder with selectionArgs? I was having a lot of trouble finding an example. (I don't want to use a rawQuery in order to avoid SQL injection.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very similar to what you have already.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

String [] sqlSelect = { KEY_WORD };
String sqlTables = TABLE_WORDS;
String selection = KEY_FUZZYWORD + " GLOB ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { searchString + "*" };
String limit = Integer.toString(WORD_QUERY_LIMIT);

qb.setTables(sqlTables);
Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, limit);
```

the key lines being

```
String selection = KEY_FUZZYWORD + " GLOB ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { searchString + "*" };
```

Further reading:

- [SQLite - GLOB Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_glob_clause.htm)
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) (scroll down to "The LIKE and GLOB operators")