# Android SQLITE does not execute queries with arguments

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select, sql-like

I fail queries with arguments, What am I doing wrong?

I need the following query:

```
cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.name=?", new String[]{"%"+nombre+"%"});
```

I tried the following and they also fail:

```
cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?", new String[]{"%"+nombre+"%"});

cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.name=?", new String[]{nombre});
```

This works:

```
cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user ", null);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks as though you want to use `LIKE` instead of `=`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this, List out users with name `foo`.

`cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?", new String[] {"foo"});`

OR

`cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?", new String[] {"foo"});`

[SQLiteDatabase rawQuery document reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Answer (score 0):

As Mike said in your comments
`cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ? ", new String[]{"%" + nombre + "%"});`

or if you really wanna use like this:

`cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user ", null);` where second parameter is null.

use escaped string instead:

`cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%" + nombre.replaceAll("'","''") + "%' ", null );`

or use `GLOB` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773892/1979882) described.

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name= '%"+ nombre + "%'", null);
```

Comment: Apart from pushing someone _away_ from using a parameterised query and into the realm of SQL injection ([obligatory XKCD link](https://xkcd.com/327/)) this still uses `=` instead of `like` (unless OP really has fields with `%Fred%` in them).