# What's the difference between LIKE and GLOB in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

What the difference in the following to query ?

```
FROM COMPANY WHERE ADDRESS  GLOB '*-*';
FROM COMPANY WHERE ADDRESS  LIKE '%-%';
```

I know unlike LIKE operator, GLOB is case sensitive. Is it the only difference ?

Comment: The other difference is GLOB can be used to search for a range of characters between square brackets, e.g. digits `FROM COMPANY WHERE ADDRESS  GLOB '*[0-9]*'` . A more complete answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280980/why-do-we-need-the-glob-clause-in-sqlite

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) says:

> The GLOB operator is similar to LIKE but uses the Unix file globbing syntax for its wildcards. Also, GLOB is case sensitive, unlike LIKE.

And that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Other difference that GLOB you can use it as regular expression
i.e. : to select fields which end with number use GLOB '*[0-9]'

to select fields which doesn't contain any number use GLOB '*[^0-9]*